# BIND sdb / mysql extension?

Tags: mysql, bind

Im investigating this as a solution to managing a (growing) openvpn based network. Im not finding much documentation - and even fewer samples. Has anyone here had experience with this?

EDIT: I found the page(s) at http://mysql-bind.sourceforge.net/index.php - but the CVS link appears to be broken.. as does the link to the 'dnsSQLpanel'

EDIT(post-mortem): I ended up using the "mysql-bind" code from sourceforge and re-building BIND. Adding entries to mysql tables for foward and reverse seems to be working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to the Project Page first, and then click "Files".

The project page for MySQLBIND is http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-bind/

The project page for dnsSQLpanel is http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnsqlpanel/

Comment: Thanks - that's a start. Im still a bit puzzled about how to update the 'named.conf' file w/re forward and reverse lookups. (IE zone "foo.bar" and zone "1.168.192")

Comment: I attempted to mess with the SQL/BIND thing, but we ended up just integrating DNS into AD here and I lost interest. You've reached the end of my knowledge on this one :-)

Comment: Oh well. I tried to 'up vote' your answer but I guess Im too new here.

Comment: @ethrbunny You can still accept it, with the check mark under the voting counter.